# js override console.log if not defined

Tags: javascript, console, firebug

Which solution do you recommend, the second is simpler ( less code ), but there are drawbacks on using it ?

**First:** (Set a global debug flag)

```
// the first line of code
var debug = true;
try {
    console.log
} catch(e) {
    if(e) {
        debug=false;
    }
};
// Then later in the code
if(debug) {
    console.log(something);
}
```

**Second:**  override console.log

```
try {
    console.log
} catch(e) {
    if (e) {
        console.log = function() {}
    }
};
// And all you need to do in the code is
console.log(something);
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Neither, but a variation of the second.  Lose the `try...catch` and check for existence of the console object properly:

```
if (typeof console == "undefined") {
    window.console = {
        log: function () {}
    };
}

console.log("whatever");
```

Comment: Presumably you either want to do `this.console = ...` or `var console = ...`? As you have it at the moment, you'd get an error in ECMAScript 5 strict mode.

Comment: @Tim: thanks, it was an oversight.  I think `window.console` would be best for portability.

Comment: Portability in the sense of being able to move this code into a function, rather than portability between environments?

Comment: Should you test typeof window.console since you're setting window.console later? Or should window. be removed?

Comment: Definitely check out the solution by Suresh below - he is also defining other console methods that may not be defined.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console for a full list of all console methods available and what the browser support is like.

Answer (score 6):

Or, in coffeescript:

```
window.console ?=
    log:-> #patch so console.log() never causes error even in IE.
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** *[Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3767958/67945) is way more elegant than the quick hack I've posted below.*

I generally use this approach...

```
// prevent console errors on browsers without firebug
if (!window.console) {
    window.console = {};
    window.console.log = function(){};
}
```

Comment: I like your version Frankie, but I'm not sure that it works safely across all browsers.  I remember using this and still getting occasional issues with one of the IE versions, perhaps because `console` object is only defined when the console window is open in IE9.  I think I had to do an 'undefined' check like Andy E suggested.

Comment: @Simon this comes late as a comment but only saw it today. Andy's solution is way more elegant than this quick hack I've posted. You should use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced a similar bug in my past, and I overcame it with the code below:

```
if(!window.console) {
    var console = {
        log : function(){},
        warn : function(){},
        error : function(){},
        time : function(){},
        timeEnd : function(){}
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this different than Frankie or Andy_E answers ?

Comment: The answer by Suresh is better in that he is also defining other methods that will not be defined along with log.  Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console for a full list of all functions that may (or may not) be defined.

Comment: This won't work if it's called from within a function. Instead of `var console` it should be `window.console` or just `console`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post, which is similar to the other answers:

http://jennyandlih.com/resolved-logging-firebug-console-breaks-ie

Answer (score 0):

The following will achieve what you are looking for:

```
window.console && console.log('foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.console = window.console || {};
window.console.log = window.console.log || function() {};
```